# what does the stroke over the text mean in inspect in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, inspect

what does this black bar/stroke over the text in Chrome inspect mean, the check-box is still checked so it's a little confusing for me.[picture of the inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkSJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

It means that the particular style option has been overridden by a different selector or attribute elsewhere.